# USACO 2016 - Load Balancing Optimal Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

This problem appeared in the USACO 2016 February Contest, Bronze Division (Question 3)

> Farmer John's NN cows are each standing at distinct locations
>   (x1,y1)…(xn,yn) on his two-dimensional farm (1 ≤ N ≤ 100), and the
>   xi's and yi's are positive odd integers of size at most B). FJ wants
>   to partition his field by building a long (effectively
>   infinite-length) north-south fence with equation x=a (a will be an
>   even integer, thus ensuring that he does not build the fence through
>   the position of any cow). He also wants to build a long (effectively
>   infinite-length) east-west fence with equation y=b, where b is an even
>   integer. These two fences cross at the point (a,b), and together they
>   partition his field into four regions.
>
> FJ wants to choose a and b so that the cows appearing in the four
>   resulting regions are reasonably "balanced", with no region containing
>   too many cows. Letting M be the maximum number of cows appearing in
>   one of the four regions, FJ wants to make M as small as possible.
>   Please help him determine this smallest possible value for M.
>
> For the first five test cases, B is guaranteed to be at most 100. In
>   all test cases, B is guaranteed to be at most 1,000,000.

I used a brute-force algorithm to get the first 5 test cases correct, which ran in about O(n^2) time, but obviously if B is a large number this wouldn't work out.

I then tried to reduce the time of my solution by placing the two fences near the median of the data points, but that didn't seem to work.

Code below:

```
fin = open('balancing.in', 'r');
fout = open('balancing.out', 'w');
xcows = [];
ycows = []
mincows = 10000;
N, B = map(int, fin.readline().split());
for i in range(N):
    x1, y1 = map(int, fin.readline().split());
    xcows.append(x1);
    ycows.append(y1);

xlow,ylow,xhigh,yhigh = 0,0,0,0;

xmedian = -1;
xxcows = sorted(xcows)
yycows = sorted(ycows)
if len(xxcows)%2==0:
    med = len(xxcows)//2;
    xmedian = int(xxcows[med] + xxcows[med-1])//2;
else:
    med = len(xxcows)//2;
    xmedian = xxcows[med];
xlow = (xmedian//2)-1;
xhigh = (xmedian//2)+1;

ymedian = -1;
if len(yycows)%2==0:
    med = len(yycows)//2;
    ymedian = int(yycows[med] + yycows[med-1])//2;
else:
    med = len(yycows)//2;
    ymedian = yycows[med];

ylow = (ymedian//2)-1;
yhigh = (ymedian//2)+1;

for xx in range(xlow-1, xhigh+2):
    for yy in range(ylow-1, yhigh+2):
        #place boundary at x = xx and y = yy and count cows in each quadrant
        q1, q2, q3, q4 = 0, 0, 0, 0;
        for q in range(len(xcows)):
            if xcows[q] < xx*2 and ycows[q] > yy*2:
                q1+=1;
            elif xcows[q] > xx*2 and ycows[q] > yy*2:
                q2+=1;
            elif xcows[q] < xx*2 and ycows[q] < yy*2:
                q3+=1;
            elif xcows[q] > xx*2 and ycows[q] < yy*2:
                q4+=1;
        mini = max(q1, q2, q3, q4);
        if mincows > mini:
            mincows = mini;

fout.write(str(mincows));
fin.close();
fout.close();
```

This code only got 2/10 test cases correct. I don't understand why this algorithm didn't work. If there's an even better algorithm, please feel free to share it, because I'm stumped.

Comment: Interesting.  I would think a greedy algorithm of dividing the cows along one dimension and then the other would work well.

Comment: `"O(n^2) time, but obviously if B is a large number this wouldn't work out"` - Huh? What does B have to do with n?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Would be fast but wrong :-)

Comment: @Stefan . . . Look at it another way.  If the four groups are of equal size, then the top two plus the bottom two are pretty equal to each other.  I think a greedy algorithm would work quite well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you get for a [3x3 block of nine cows and a diagonal of seven more cows coming out of a corner block](http://pastebin.com/raw/uGCUYrKD)? I think you'll get 7, not the optimal 6.

Comment: @StefanPochmann . . . The question says "reasonably balanced".  In addition, a 3x3 block can have at most 4 cows given the constraints of the problem, and there is only one cow at a given location.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But it goes on to specify exactly what is meant by that, requesting *"make M as small as possible"*. Suboptimal isn't going to get accepted, it will just be judged as "wrong". And I said 3x3 block **of cows**, not 3x3 block of locations. Obviously have empty rows/columns in between.

Comment: What is the reason that my algorithm of using the median wouldn't work? Could either of you provide an example of where using the median wouldn't provide the optimal solution?

Answer (score 1):

The solution does not depend on the size of B, only on the number of cows, N.   For every xi try putting a N-S line as xi - 1.  For every yi, try putting an E-W line at yi - 1.  Because there are at most 100 cows, there are at most 10000 cases to try.

```
import itertools as it

# your code for reading cow data goes here

for xx, yy in it.product(xcows, ycows):
    counts = [0,0,0,0]
    for x,y in cows:
        ew = 0 if x < xx else 2
        ns = 0 if y < yy else 1
        counts[ew + ns] += 1

    mini = max(counts)

# rest of you code goes here
```

Comment: Ok what would happen if say N was arbitrarily large (1 ≤ N ≤ 10000), then this algorithm wouldn't be the most optimal, because you would be checking 10000*10000 cases, which is a lot. In this case what would be the most optimal algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

For a large number of cows, a better search strategy is needed.  The following routine starts from an initial guess and tries moving the fences to the next position east-west, north-south, and diagonally to see if it improves the score.  A queue is kept of any fence positions that match the current best score.  The answer is the current best score and position when the queue is empty.

Uncomment the print statements to see how it works.

```
from collections import deque

def calc_score(ew_fence, ns_fence):
    cnts = [0,0,0,0]
    for cow in cows:
        i = (0 if cow[1] < ew_fence else 2) + (0 if cow[0] < ns_fence else 1)
        cnts[i] += 1
    return max(cnts)

def solve2(cows):
    xs,ys = zip(*cows)

    xs = sorted(x-1 for x in set(xs))
    ix = len(xs)//2

    ys = sorted(y-1 for y in set(ys))
    iy = len(ys)//2

    #print("Initial score = {} at ix,iy = ({},{})".format(calc_score(xs[ix],ys[iy]), ix, iy))

    seen = set([(ix, iy)])

    queue = deque([(ix, iy)])

    best_score, best_ix, best_iy = calc_score(xs[ix],ys[iy]), ix, iy

    while queue:
        ix, iy = queue.pop()
        #print("checking near: ix,iy = ({}, {})".format(ix, iy))

        for dx,dy in ((-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1),
                      (-1, 0),         (1, 0),
                      (-1,-1), (0,-1), (1,-1)):

            nx, ny = ix + dx, iy + dy

            if (nx,ny) in seen: 
                #print("\t({},{}) - seen".format(nx, ny))
                continue

            seen.add((nx, ny))
            score = calc_score(xs[nx], ys[ny])

            if score < best_score:
                best_score, best_ix, best_iy = score, nx, ny
                #print("\t({},{}) - new best score = {}".format(best_ix, best_iy, best_score))
                queue.clear()

            if score == best_score:
                queue.append((nx, ny))
                #print("\t({},{}) = enqueue".format(nx, ny))

    #print("\nbest score = {} at ix,iy = ({},{}) = grid coords ({},{})".format(
    #        best_score, best_ix, best_iy, xs[best_ix], ys[best_iy]))

    return best_score, (xs[best_ix], ys[best_iy])
```